# Linker error in Text Recognition (OCR) using Tesseract and OpenCV?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, ocr, linker-errors, tesseract

I have written the code to recognize text in images using Tesseract and OpenCV.But while I am executing their is no problem with code but it is showing some linker error. I am using tesseract4.0 with visual studios.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "tesseract/baseapi.h"
#include "leptonica/allheaders.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string outText;
    string imPath = "Images/newspaper2.jpeg";

    // Create Tesseract object
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();

    // Initialize tesseract to use English (eng) and the LSTM OCR engine. 
    ocr->Init("tessdata", "eng", tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);

    // Set Page segmentation mode to PSM_AUTO (3)
    ocr->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);

    // Open input image using OpenCV
    Mat im = imread(imPath, IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Set image data
    ocr->SetImage(im.data, im.cols, im.rows, 3, im.step);

    // Run Tesseract OCR on image
    outText = string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());

    // print recognized text
    cout << outText << endl; // Destroy used object and release memory ocr->End();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My error looks like this.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol closesocket  opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol connect  opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol htons    opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol recv opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol select   opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol send opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol gethostbyname    opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol socket   opencv1 C:\Users\Muskan Agarwal\Dropbox\Personal\opencv1\opencv1\tesseract40.lib(svutil.cpp.obj)    1
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution to above problem. Actually I was trying to run a 64 bit code and use a32 bit library. So there was a linking error. So now again build tesseract for 32 bit and use it will work. For reference you can see here https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1490.